# Grails 3 app is 404 in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: grails, jboss, jboss-eap-6, grails-3.1

If I create a new web profile app, and generate-all, it runs fine in my local and deploys without error to JBoss. But when I try to access the app all URLs return 404. I know the app started up successfully, because it created tables in the database.

Here's what I'm doing.

1. grails 3.1.4> create-app demo
2. create-domain-class Book
3. create-domain-class Author
4. Edit domain classes
5. generate-all *
6. change tomcat dependency from compile to provided in build.gradle
7. change dataSource in application.yml to use my JNDI Oracle connection
8. Add server: contextPath: /demo to application.yml
9. run-app -> Works
10. gradle war
11. Deploy to JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA

JBoss says deployment and activation of the app was successful. There are no errors of any sort in any JBoss log file. And dbCreate: update made the DDL changes to my Oracle database, so I know it got that far. But all URLs for the app return 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug: [Issue-9481](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9481)

It has been added to grails 3.1.5 milestone.